# Why does my bootstrap grid looks different on stackoverflow and on localhost?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I clicked on "external library" and added the bootstrap library, but as you can see if you click on the run button, the rows are not displayed in one row.

```css
/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
        Text
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
        Text
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
        Text
  </div>
</div>
```

If i execute the same code on my local machine then it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please switch to Full-page view

Comment: Thank you i did not noticed this

Comment: the iframe which contains this code preview has a width < 768px so col-sm have no effect

Comment: Bootstrap's grid system is responsive and the columns will re-arrange depending on the screen size. So if you switch to full page view the columns will be re-arranged in single line.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the view your looking at is too small and as bootstrap works it's getting re-sized one at a line. If you take a look in the full page view, you will see the following image :

[image]